# python pandas re:search throws error: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, pandas

**PROBLEM:**

I'm following a tutorial and trying to do a re.search on a csv file, which contains tweet (date, username, the tweet itself, the tweet id, and whether it's true or false).

This is my original code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

filename = 'sample.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')

print(data.info())

def word_in_text(word,text):
     match = re.search(word,text)

     if match:
         return True
     return False

[kai, hatsu] = [0, 0]

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    kai += word_in_text('会', row['text'])
    hatsu += word_in_text('初', row['text'])
```

And this is the error it throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python\enkousaiTF.py", line 28, in <module>
kai += word_in_text('会', row['text'])
File "C:\Python\enkousaiTF.py", line 19, in word_in_text
match = re.search(word,text)
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\re.py", line 182, in search
return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

**WHAT I TRIED TO FIX THE PROBLEM:**

When I tried to find out what type the dataframe is, I got this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1001 entries, 0 to 1000
Data columns (total 5 columns):
date        1000 non-null object
username    1000 non-null object
text        1000 non-null object
id          1000 non-null float64
enko        1000 non-null object
dtypes: float64(1), object(4)
memory usage: 23.5+ KB
```

So, I figured maybe the float64 type was the problem, so I tried to add str here:

```
match = re.search(str(word,text))
```

But it just throws another error:

```
TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

And then I tried changing the data type with

```
dtype_dic= {'date': str, 
            'username' : str,
            'text': str,
            'id': str,
            'enko': str}
```

But it's still throws the `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`, even though when I checked the data type it's all `object`

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What happens when you change the `'会'` by some other "normal" string like `'foo'`? Is the error still showing up on the same line?

Comment: @JosuéCortina yes, sadly it still does throw the same error on the same line

Comment: And if you replace `row['text']` by `'foo'`?. Also, tell me what is the output of `type(row['text'])`?

Comment: the `type(row['text'])` is `<class 'str'>`. I think maybe something is wrong with the data, because when I try to print how many times 会 is in the document, it shows the correct number(190), but then **after that** it throws the error so.. I checked the data and found the problem there. For some reason at the end of the data there's this three comma `,,,` and when I deleted it everything works just fine.... Really sorry for this

Answer (score 1):

Likely your text file is not unicode supported. Check this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and check for formatting.